# Jquery Mobile & PhoneGap - Android Port issue

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

Running into an issue on certain models of android phones. Overall app works but have been getting consistent reports of 'Content appearing and then disappears'. Basically content flashes and then goes away. I have been able to reproduce this on on of my device(HP touchpad running cyanogenmod). Not sure how to debug it but had some limited success in content to appear if content area is set to data-position="fixed" but obviously that breaks lot of other screen elements. 
At this point, I am not even sure where to go from here and am hoping that someone ran into it or possibly be able to point me in right direction.

Appreciated and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it. Posting it here so it may help someone else..

I had flickering issue with iOS version so added -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; for body tag but this is what caused blank screen on some of android devices/versions..
So for android port, get rid of -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;

Will post here if anything else comes up...